# Propose that the apostolic-fathers tag synonym be removed

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I propose that the tag synonym `apostolic-fathers` currently linked to `church-fathers` be **removed** for these reasons:

1. [Apostolic Fathers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostolic_Fathers) is a special group, having known the apostles personally, and therefore for *sola scriptura* proponents their writings would have more weight than the others.
2. Within the academia, more books are published specifically about Apostolic Fathers such as:

   - 2018 [The Apostolic Fathers: A New Translation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1683590643)
   - 2017 [The Apostolic Fathers: A Narrative Introduction](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0711HS4NG)
   - 2010 [The Apostolic Fathers - An Introduction](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1602583080)
   - 2006 [Apostolic Fathers in English, 3rd Ed.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0085BA9G6)
   - 2005 [A Theological and Historical Introduction to the Apostolic Fathers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1597523151)
3. There are plenty enough questions tagged `church-fathers` (currently 186)

I can write the tag wiki on it, which will be based on commonly accepted definition, to include the writings of 3 known figures (Ignatius of Antioch, Clement of Rome, Polycarp of Smyrna) as well as *Didache*, *Shepherd of Hermas*, *Epistle of Barnabas*, etc. listed in the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostolic_Fathers#List_of_works) article.  Once that done, we can re-tag existing questions.

I just posted 2 questions which can use the new tag: [this](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/78083/10672) and [this](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/78084/what-was-the-dominant-theory-of-atonement-shown-in-the-apostolic-fatherss-writi).

Comment: As it stands now, the description of "apostolic-fathers" says it covers people up to the 7th century, which is definitely wrong.  So yes, make it a real tag with a correct definition.

Comment: @RayButterworth I'd like to, but I need to break it off the [synonym](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tags/church-fathers/synonyms) first, but I may not have the privilege to do so.

Comment: I removed the tag synonym.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that's an OK idea. I'd prefer [church-fathers](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/church-fathers) end with St. Augustine and have one tag, not linger until 700 just to squeeze in a few more Saints.

If we do this, I'd suggest, if possible, to keep [church-fathers](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/church-fathers) and [apostolic-fathers](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apostolic-fathers) on questions you retag.

SEO vs Academia and professionalism is a delicate balance, but I think these Saints can be both Church-Fathers and Apostolic-Fathers.

---

I removed the Tag Synonym, go nuts (little by little, please)

Speaking of patriarchs, could we fix up the "[joseph](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joseph)" vs "[joseph-husband-of-mary](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joseph-husband-of-mary)" tags.

Comment: Yeah I'd agree the apostolic fathers are a subset of the church fathers, so using both tags is appropriate. But I think the church fathers tag should include those up to around 700AD, that seems conventional (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_Fathers), [newadvent.org](https://www.newadvent.org/fathers/) etc).

Comment: CC @curiousdannii Yes I will keep both.  But can either of you broke the synonym so both tags exist independently?  I cannot seem to do it myself, or maybe I don't have the privilege.

Comment: Thst requires a mod.